# get ids of all inserted records by last query executed in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, lastinsertid

I can find the primary key id of last inserted record as follows:

```
$this->Model->save($record);
$id = $this->Model->getLastInsertId();
```

I am looking for something like this:

```
$this->Model->saveAll($records);
$ids = $this->Model->getLastInsertIds();
```

I am inserting 100s of records, so its better to insert them all in a single query. Still its taking some seconds to execute the use case. Is there a way to get all ids of inserted records by last query?

This was asked in many forums, but there are no clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work and might be what you are looking for:

```
$this->Model->saveAll($records);
$id1 = $this->Model1->id();
$id2 = $this->Model2->id();
$id3 = $this->Model3->id();
...
```

Remember to replace model1,model2,model3 with each of the models that you are saving to.

Have you looked at the cakephp tutorial on saving your data? here is the link:
http://book.cakephp.org/view/1031/Saving-Your-Data

Hope this helps.

Comment: But I am adding all the 100s of records in the same model.

Comment: did you want the range? e.g. 7 - 106. If so, just get the first and the last id, and you should have your range